# Solving the merge-and-order pairs problem, when there is more than 2 pairs

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of pairs of objects that I need to order, and ovelapping or neighbouring pairs must be merged. The original order of the pairs in the input-list is random, and have no importance. Inside each pair we can be certain that the first value are never larger than the second value.
Looking at this example with integers.

```
lst = [[1, 4], [17, 20], [2, 3], [16, 18], [6, 6], [6, 7], [9, 13], [21, 24]]
```

Two pairs should merge if:

- they are overlapping, e.g. [16, 18] and [17, 20] -> [16, 20]
- they are immediate neighbours, e.g. [17, 20] and [21, 24] -> [17, 24]
- specifically [6, 6] and [6, 7] should also merge, and become [6, 7]

Then all pairs should be sorted (that is easy), so looking at example-data the final result becomes:

```
ref = [[1, 4], [6, 7], [9, 13], [16, 24]]
```

I do have a function mrg2pairs(pair_a, pair_b) that will return a list of one or two pairs. One merged pair if merging is appropriate, otherwise the original two pairs are returned, in a list.
This takes care of the 2-pair situation, I'm looking to find a smooth way to deal with longer lists.
Maybe something recursive, using the mrg2pairs(), but I can't envision the solution.

```
def mrg2pairs(pair_a, pair_b):
    """ Merge two pairs
    :param pair_a: First pair
    :param pair_b: Second pair
    :return: A list of, one or two, pairs, each same format as pair_a and pair_b
    """
    a1, a2 = pair_a[0], pair_a[1]
    b1, b2 = pair_b[0], pair_b[1]
    if a1 < b1:
        if (b1 - a2) > 1:  # a entirely before b
            return [pair_a, pair_b]  # return untouched
        elif a2 == b1:  # a-end touching b-start
            return [[a1, b2]]  # merge
        else:
            if a2 < b2: # a overlapping b-start
                return [[a1, b2]]
            else:  # a encapsulating b
                return [pair_a]  # return a
    else:
        if a1 < b2:
            if a2 > b2:  # a overlapping b-end
                return [[b1, a2]]
            else:  # a inside b
                return [pair_b]  # return b
        else:
            if (a1 - b2) > 1:  # a entirely after b
                return [pair_a, pair_b]  # return untouched
            else:  # a-start touching b-end
                return [[b1, a2]]  # merge
```

This function is tested and works just fine - The question is how to go from the 2-pair case to the n-paris in a list case.

I need to solve this in Python - any suggestions are welcome, but I prefer Pythonic elegant.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried & what problem(s) you had with it.

Comment: Thanks Scott, but this is more of an algorithmic question, I haven't got any code - yet

Comment: Then what is your best attempt at an algorithm?

Comment: Thanks Scott, but that is exactly where I'm hoping to get some inspiration from the forum - I havn't been able to come up with a brilliant idea for an algorithmic approach.

Comment: You can do a one-liner with reduce, but I think a regular for loop would be more readable. First sort the intervals and then think about what you would do on paper.

Comment: Algorithms can't be "pythonic". Code can be pythonic.

Comment: Thanks @thejonny. A regular for loop is not obvious, as you should never loop over a list and change the list at the same time - that is a direct road to trouble in Python.  I would like to see your suggested one-lines and/or for-loop though.

Comment: @thejonny: reduce is a convenient option. But it works best with simpler functions. In this case print(reduce(mrg2pairs, sorted(lst))) only results in an error, because it tries to pass a list in place of an integer, likely during the second call, but it's not easy to debug.

Comment: yes you are right, one should not mutate the list while iterating, but create a new one

Comment: there was a tiny error in the mrg2pairs() that was introduced duing my porting it from the original code to a simplified int-version. It is now corrected... My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bisect module to obtain an O(NlogN) solution wihout actually sorting:

```
lst = [[1, 4], [17, 20], [2, 3], [16, 18], [6, 6], [6, 7], [9, 13], [21, 24]]

from bisect import bisect_left
starts = []  # merged starting values
ends   = []  # merged ending values
for (start,end) in lst:
    iLeft  = bisect_left(ends,start-1) # first position after start
    iRight = bisect_left(starts,end+1) # first position after end
    starts[iLeft:iRight] = [min([start]+starts[iLeft:iLeft+1])] # insert/merge
    ends[iLeft:iRight]   = [max([end]+ends[iRight-1:iRight])]        
merged = list(zip(starts,ends)) # combine starts and ends

print(merged)
[(1, 4), (6, 7), (9, 13), (16, 24)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below works, but I don't find it quite as elegant as I had hoped possible.

```
def mrg_many(lst_pairs):
    """ Merge many pairs
    :param lst_pairs: List of pairs
    :return: A list of pairs, where all appropriate merges is made
    """
    lst_ret = [itm for itm in lst_pairs]  # deep copy
    lst_rem = list()
    for n in range(len(lst_pairs)):
        for m in range(n+1, len(lst_pairs)):
            mp_ret = mrg2pairs(lst_pairs[n], lst_pairs[m])
            if len(mp_ret) == 1:
                if mp_ret[0] not in lst_ret:
                    lst_ret.append(mp_ret[0])
                lst_rem.extend([itm for itm in [lst_pairs[n], lst_pairs[m]] if itm not in mp_ret])
    lst_resul = [itm for itm in lst_ret if itm not in lst_rem]
    if any([itm not in lst_resul for itm in lst_pairs]):  # at least one pair from input disappeared
        return mrg_many(lst_resul)
    return lst_resul
```